# Find subset with minimal sum under constraints

Tags: algorithms, reductions, optimization

Let $M$ be a finite set of even cardinality. Define $C=\{\{a,b\}:a,b \in M, a \neq b\}$ the set of all pairs over $M$. Let $w:C \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+_0$ be a function.

Now find $C' \subset C$ with the following constraints:

$$
\bigcup C' = M \\
\forall x,y \in C': x \cap y = \emptyset \\
\sum_{x \in C'}w(x) \text{ minimal}
$$

In words: Find a subset $C'$ of pair-wise disjunctive pairs over $M$ that covers $M$, with the sum of these pairs being minimal. Any element of $M$ must appear in exactly one pair.

I could not find an efficient algorithmic solution, and I also fail to relate this to any other known (optimization) problem. I was thinking of the subset sum problem, but I don't see any relation.

So the questions is: Can you find an efficient algorithm to find $C'$? A good approximation might also be sufficient. If not, can you reduce this to any other known computer science problem?

Comment: The weight function is completely arbitrary.

Comment: oh, that was not clear from the question - this makes more sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is known as *minimum-weight perfect matching*, and can be solved in polynomial time using several different algorithms. One algorithm that can be used is Edmonds' [Blossom algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm). See also [Cook and Rohe](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~bico/papers/match_ijoc.pdf), who discuss how to implement Blossom.

Comment: Wow. Can't believe I didn't see that (M, C) is a graph. Thank you very much.